# Merge multiple JS files into 1 JS files

Tags: javascript

I have around 40 JS files on all pages that needs to be loaded.How can I merge multiple js files into 1 JS file , So that I have to make less http request.

Comment: For example in linux: `find . -type f -name '*.js' -exec cat {} + >> combined.js`, windows: `type *.js > combined.js`

Comment: Are you asking about a build or deployment tool that will do this automatically while keeping the source files separate for ongoing development work?

Comment: Not sure of your environment but you could use a *Bundling* tool. Bundles files into a single call.

Comment: You can use a task runner appropriate to the language and development environment you are using. For me, using node.js, grunt or gulp does the job with appropriate plugins.

Comment: Keep in mind that you may have to make less HTTP requests, but if your file is suddenly 5 MB large it might take users *a long time* before loading the js file the first time. Are you really using all 40 JS files on every single page?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes i am trying to do what u r saying

Comment: @pawel this command is not working i am getting this error cat: ./combined.js: input file is output file

Comment: have a look at js bundling tools - there's some good ones out there that will minify when it bundles them

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use a task runner such as gulp.  Read more on how to install it [here](http://gulpjs.com/)

The following would merge all `.js` files in the `./assets/js` directory into one file in the `./public/js` directory.

```
// Require gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Require plugins
var concat = require('gulp-concat');


gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(['./assets/js/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'));
});
```

It is then possible to run this script with `gulp scripts` in the command line from within the project directory.

Comment: this would, of course, require node.js to be installed!

Comment: @ChaudhryJunaid it would indeed, worth it though to bring your requests down from 40 to 1!

Answer (score 0):

Use automation tools like Gulp or Grunt to concatenate, minify, build sourcemaps, and do everything you want with your sources. Sample build script looks like this:

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    concat     = require('gulp-concat'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('build-js', function() {
  return gulp.src('source/javascript/**/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/javascript'));
});
```

After that everything you need is run `gulp build-js`

Comment: I am not able to understand any solution ...Can anyone help me out in this.